# disabled = true can be set dynamically on <style>. Why not statically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

To disable `<style>` blocks, all browsers allow setting `document.styleSheets[x].disabled = true`. However, only IE allows this property to be set on the tag itself, `<style disabled="true">`. Is there a workaround for this in other browsers? It seems odd that something done dynamically can't also be done statically.

Comment: It think `true` might be an invalid value of the `disabled` attribute. Try `disabled="disabled"`

Comment: Add an onload event on the style tag: ``onload="this.disabled=true"``

Answer (score 8):

The `style` element has no valid attribute named `disabled`. From [the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3):

```
<!ELEMENT STYLE - - %StyleSheet        -- style info -->
<!ATTLIST STYLE
  %i18n;                               -- lang, dir, for use with title --
  type        %ContentType;  #REQUIRED -- content type of style language --
  media       %MediaDesc;    #IMPLIED  -- designed for use with these media --
  title       %Text;         #IMPLIED  -- advisory title --
  >
```

However, the `HTMLStyleElement` DOM interface does have such a property. From [the DOM spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-16428977):

```
interface HTMLStyleElement : HTMLElement {
           attribute boolean         disabled;
           attribute DOMString       media;
           attribute DOMString       type;
};
```

Don't confuse an HTML element with its counterpart in the DOM. It is not *"odd that something done dynamically can't also be done statically."* The HTML and DOM specs were created to solve different problems. HTML is a markup language. The DOM is a convention for representing and interacting with the objects in a document.

Comment: So no workaround? IE does what's reasonable while everyone else blindly follows the standard.

Comment: @Lucent - I disagree with your characterization. IE unnecessarily diverts from the standard, while everyone else does what's reasonable (i.e. follows the standard where there's not an obvious and compelling reason not to). The DOM and HTML are separate things. You should not conflate their respective standards. It is *not* "odd that something done dynamically can't also be done statically", because these are different standards with different purposes.

Comment: @Lucent - not really. It mostly works the other way round, in that the standard records either what browsers already do, or what they have indicated a willingness to do. What they are willing to do is what they think there is a demand for from users - it's the users that provide their revenue stream. That, in turn, depends on users being able to use the web pages created by web authors, and in this case, there simply isn't sufficient demand from users or authors to have this feature, ahead of other things they could be implementing.

Comment: I think a structure's model should reflect what it's modelling. Not everything is logical for everyone in the same way I guess.

Answer (score 8):

Extending on the `media` answer by @lampyridae, you can negate a media selector using `not`. To disable a style tag statically, I use `media="not all"`, which works for me in Chrome 79.

Comment: Very elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

The `media` attribute can be set both in the HTML and by Javascript. The idea is to set the `media` attribute so that the style tag does not apply to any device in order to disable it.

I think setting it to something invalid like `media="bogus"` or `media="none"` is risky since the browser may decide to simply ignore the predicate and apply the style to all media types. Fortunately, setting a max screen width of one pixel is quite valid and in my book that's pretty much the same as disabling the style tag.

```js
 var style = document.querySelector("#my-style");

 document.querySelector("#btn-style").addEventListener("click",function() {
    style.removeAttribute("media");
 });

 document.querySelector("#btn-unstyle").addEventListener("click",function() {
    style.setAttribute("media", "max-width: 1px");
 });
```

```html
<style id="my-style" media="max-width: 1px">
   p { color: red }
</style>

<p>Styled if you click below.</p>

<button id="btn-style">Style that p</button>

<button id="btn-unstyle">Unstyle that p</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! Brilliant! I'll take this hack. I'm building a tool that applies `<link>` and `<style>` tags to a page with a toggle and this method works fast in updating the UI faster than my first approach.

Comment: this work around is correct. actually setting the ```type``` attribute to whatever random string will also disable the style block without remove it entirely

Comment: Any reason not to use max-width: 0px ?

Comment: max-width < 0px works in firefox, at least, which returns it as "not all", which would be an even more obvious alternative syntax.

Answer (score 2):

To do it statically, just remove the style tag.

As an alternative, you could remove the style node from the DOM, and re-insert it to re-enable it.

Comment: And what if you want to dynamically add it later?

Comment: @Peter of the Corn, but then it's not static anymore is it?

Comment: I'm sure the use case here is to start off with the styles statically disabled, but have them available to be dynamically enabled later.

Answer (score 2):

One simple option is to make it an alternate stylesheet with a different title than the main stylesheet set.  That will make browsers default it to disabled.

Comment: It would be good if the examples in [CSSOM section 5.2.5](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#examples) included a use of the style element